# All vs All comparisons on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

We are planning to use MongoDB for a general purpose system and it seems well suited to the particular data and use cases we have.

However we have one use case where we will need to compare every document (of which there could be 10s of millions) with every other document. The 'distance measure' could be pre computed offline by another system but we are concerned about the online performance of MongoDB when we want to query - eg when we want to see the top 10 closest documents in the entire collection to a list of specific documents ...

Is this likely to be slow? Also can this be done across documents (eg query for the top10 closest documents in one collection to a document in another collection)...

Thanks in advance,

FK

Comment: You should understand that the case here is very broad without a specific example. The basics of databases is that you ideally want a defined criteria that you can ideally select by value or range for the best performance, and calculated values basically mean inspecting each document unless some other feature can be used. So some definition of what "closest" means in real world application as an example would help with definitive answers.

Comment: "Also can this be done across documents (eg query for the top10 closest documents in one collection to a document in another collection)" This for sure not, MongoDB does not support operations across collections or joins. Within the same collection should be possible by using the Aggregation Framework. I cannot tell about performance though.

Comment: Hi - ok so an example would be imagine each document relates to some time series data (eg some period of time) and the distance between documents is recorded as some mathematical metric between the two time series. So 'close' would mean the metric is small...Or, equally, the documents could be user profiles and the metric would again be some mathematical metric between the profiles...